# Why i can't use my column in WHERE while i can in GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

I there any particular reason about MySQL not allowing the use of `date_sent_at` in `WHERE` while allowing it in `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(type, '_', IF(om.is_auto, 'auto', 'user')) AS subtype,
    DATE(om.sent_at) AS date_sent_at,
    COUNT(om.id) AS sends
FROM outgoing_message om INNER JOIN outgoing_message_customers AS omc
    ON om.id = omc.outgoing_message_id
WHERE
    omc.customer_id = 2
    AND
    om.status <> 'pending'
    AND
    date_sent_at >= '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY subtype, date_sent_at
```

**EDIT**: i know that (of course) i can replace with `DATE(om.sent_at) >= '2012-01-01'`.

Comment: no - should work. what's your error message?

Comment: @Horen Unknown column 'date_sent_at' in 'where clause'.

Comment: concerning your edit: if you know that you were probably looking for the answer @user868766 gave you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: @Horen sorry for the mistake, i know that can use DATE... but i didn't know that ALIASes can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use alias in where But can use in GROUP BY

As written in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) docs here:

```
A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses. For example:
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `DATE(om.sent_at) as date_sent_at`. The `AS` part won't work in the `WHERE` clause but does work in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Try this:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(type, '_', IF(om.is_auto, 'auto', 'user')) AS subtype,
DATE(om.sent_at) as date_sent_at,
COUNT(om.id) as sends
FROM outgoing_message om INNER JOIN outgoing_message_customers AS omc
ON om.id = omc.outgoing_message_id
WHERE
omc.customer_id = 2 and om.status <> 'pending'
AND
DATE(om.sent_at) > '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY subtype, date_sent_at
```

Answer (score 1):

Can not use alias in the WHERE clause. Should use complete sentence `DATE(om.sent_at) >`

Answer (score 1):

You can not use column aliases in where clause but you can use them in having clause instead.

Use following condition in where clause:

```
DATE(om.sent_at) > '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

date_sent_at is a alias name ..  you have to give DATE(om.sent_at) in the where clause

pleae see the  [the order of operations in a SELECT statement](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-use-a-select-list-alias-in-the-where-or-group-by-clause.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the column alias your gave the column in the SELECT list in the WHERE clause. You have the use the expression you used to construct the column:

```
SELECT        CONCAT(type, '_', IF(om.is_auto, 'auto', 'user')) AS subtype,
              DATE(om.sent_at) as date_sent_at,
              COUNT(om.id) as sends
FROM          outgoing_message om 
INNER JOIN    outgoing_message_customers AS omc
ON            om.id = omc.outgoing_message_id
WHERE         omc.customer_id = 2
AND           om.status <> 'pending'
AND           DATE(om.sent_at) >= '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY      subtype, date_sent_at
```